# Get realtime title and featured image value in Wordpress block

Tags: block-editor, react

I'm building a WordPress block in React, and I need the title and featured image to be displayed in the block. So I need a way to get the title value and the featured img URL in real time, so it should update when typing in the title field or when changing the featured image. Does anyone have any suggestions?
Having a separate title and image field in the block itself does not work for me, I need to be able to get the values from the default block editor title and feature image fields.

I can use `select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("title")` to get the value of the title field, but I cant figure out how to fire it every time the user types in the title field.

I basically want to do something like

```
const [newPostTitle, setNewPostTitle] = useState("");
const postTitle = wp.data.select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("title");
useEffect(() => {
   setNewPostTitle(postTitle)
}, [postTitle])
```

and use the `newPostTitle` in my jsx.
I have tried to use

```
{wp.data.select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("title")}
```

in my jsx but this also wouldn't update every time I type in the title field.

PS: Does anyone know where I can find a list of the attributes for

```
select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute(...)
```

that would also help me out a lot.

Comment: "I cant figure out how to fire it every time the user types in the title field." You shouldn't need to. The value should stay up to date as it changed. Can you share your code showing how you're attempting to use it?

Comment: I basically want to do something like `const [newPostTitle, setNewPostTitle] = useState("");
  const postTitle = wp.data.select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("title");
  

  useEffect(() => {
    setNewPostTitle(postTitle)
  }, [postTitle])` and use the `newPostTitle` in my jsx. I have tried to use `{wp.data.select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("title")}` in my jsx but this also wouldn't update every time I type in the title field.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/419066/edit) to include your code snippet. Code formatting in comments is pretty bad.